# Multiline UILabel with auto layout does not work

Tags: ios, storyboard, uilabel, autolayout, multiline

I'm trying to set constraints to get a multiline label in a static table view cell, but apparently this does not work for me, the label is still in one single line. I've set the numberOfLines property to 0 and also the height constraint to greater than or equal. And I'm setting the height for the cell correctly in `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath`. Please have a look at my screenshot to see the settings in IB.

[image]

Comment: And what doesn't work about it?

Comment: @ScottBerrevoets Sry, I updated my question. The label is still in one single line

Comment: Is the address long enough to fit on two lines? Did you set the `preferredMaxLayoutWidth`?

Comment: Yes, it is, I tried it also with a hardcoded long string. No, I'm currently not setting the `preferredMaxLayoutWidth`, where should I set this property and does this change the height as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the comments above you mentioned you're not currently setting `preferredMaxLayoutWidth`. This property tells your label that it should lay out its text over the width of that property's value. In UILabel.h:

> If nonzero, this is used when determining -intrinsicContentSize for multiline labels

In other words, if you don't set that, the label's intrinsic content size is whatever width the label needs to draw its text. If you set this property to the label's bounds, it will start drawing on the next line (or else it will cut the text off if `numberOfLines` is 0).

In your case, I would probably do that in `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: numberOfLines = 0 is an unlimited number of lines, so it shouldn't cut the text off unless he has a different word wrap property in place.

Comment: What I (think I) meant to say was: if you don't set `intrinsicContentSize` to the label's bounds and `numberOfLines` is 0, it will cut the text off. I've updated my answer for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` in code, but when designing your user interface in storyboard, you still see a long one-line label that gets cut off at the edges. An alternative is to manually insert line breaks anywhere in your text right within the storyboard using `Option-Return`. You then just set the number of lines to more than your text will fit. Then select your label, hit `Cmd-=`. This will calculate the intrinsic content size for your label with the line breaks exactly where you want them to be.

Theoretically, I think setting the `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` is the more correct way to go about this, especially using Autolayout. However, I found it more practical to use the method I described above because it lets you see the layout at design time right in the storyboard, and you have total control of your line breaks. This usually works better for labels with text that don't change often. If you are dynamically changing the label text, setting `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` is the preferred way.